# How to access NiFi remotely?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to know if I can access NiFi installed on a server from any other system. I would like to access NiFi remotely. How can I access to NiFi remotely ?

Comment: it is designed to access remotely through your browser. please describe your problem with details. what do you mean by "access"?

Comment: Do you mean access a secured NiFi behind proxy? Access without using the UI(Rest API)?